# send '%' in cut command (linux)

Tags: linux, bash, vbscript, cut

I am wring a script using VBScript. This script needs to run in CMD and connect to a system with Linux OS. I need to use the `cut` command to take a specific number. When I am trying to send `%` via the script it sends .

Any ides?

This is the code:

```vb
oShell.SendKeys "cat /tmp/dftemp1.txt | cut -d'%' -f1 > /tmp/dftemp2.txt"
```

When I use my code in secureCRT it's working. When I copy the line and paste manually in CMD line it's working too. It's not working when trying to run it automatclly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

> The **SendKeys** method uses some characters as modifiers of characters (instead of using their face-values). This set of special characters consists of parentheses, brackets, braces, and the:
>
> plus sign `+`,
>       caret `^`,
>       percent sign `%`,
>       and tilde `~`
>
> Send these characters by enclosing them within braces "{}". For example, to send the plus sign, send the string argument "{+}".

Change this:

```
oShell.SendKeys "cat /tmp/dftemp1.txt | cut -d'%' -f1 > /tmp/dftemp2.txt"
```

into this:

```
oShell.SendKeys "cat /tmp/dftemp1.txt | cut -d'{%}' -f1 > /tmp/dftemp2.txt"
```

**Or**, use something like [`plink`](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.67/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink) (from the [PuTTY suite](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)), so you don't need to fiddle around with `SendKeys` in the first place.

```
plink user@host "cat /tmp/dftemp1.txt | cut -d'%' -f1 > /tmp/dftemp2.txt"
```

Comment: It's amazing what happens when you *[read the documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM)*.